# java if else errors not working properly

Tags: java, if-statement

```
private void registerActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
 if (compName==null){JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(new JFrame(), "Company Name required", "Error",
         JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);}
 else{
     if(regNo==null){JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(new JFrame(), "Registration number required", "Error",
             JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);}
     else{
         if(addressL1==null){JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(new JFrame(), "Address required", "Error",
                 JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);}
         else{
             if(postcode==null){JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(new JFrame(), "postcode required", "Error",
                     JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);}
             else {
                 if(username==null){JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(new JFrame(), "Username required", "Error",
                         JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);}
                 else{
                     if(password==null){JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(new JFrame(), "Password required", "Error",
                             JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);}
                     else{
                         BufferedWriter output;
                         try {
                             File user = new File(username.getText()+".txt");
                             output = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(user));
                             output.write(compName.getText());
                             output.append(System.lineSeparator());
                             output.write(regNo.getText());
                             output.append(System.lineSeparator());
                             output.write((String) Day.getSelectedItem()+(String) Month.getSelectedItem()+(String) Year.getSelectedItem());
                             output.append(System.lineSeparator());
                             output.write(addressL1.getText()+addressL3.getText()+addressL3.getText());
                             output.append(System.lineSeparator());
                             output.write(postcode.getText());
                             output.append(System.lineSeparator());
                             output.write(email.getText());
                             output.append(System.lineSeparator());
                             output.write(mobile.getText());
                             output.append(System.lineSeparator());
                             output.write(username.getText());
                             output.append(System.lineSeparator());
                             output.write(password.getText());
                             output.append(System.lineSeparator());
                             output.close();
                         } catch ( IOException IOe ) {

                         }
                         dispose();       // TODO add your handling code here:
                     }
                 }
             }
         }
     }
 }
    }                                        

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(regcomp.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(regcomp.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(regcomp.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(regcomp.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new regcomp().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JComboBox Day;
    private javax.swing.JComboBox Month;
    private javax.swing.JComboBox Year;
    private javax.swing.JTextField addressL1;
    private javax.swing.JTextField addressL2;
    private javax.swing.JTextField addressL3;
    private javax.swing.JLabel addressLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel addressLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel addressLabel3;
    private javax.swing.JTextField compName;
    private javax.swing.JLabel companyLabel;
    private javax.swing.JTextField email;
    private javax.swing.JLabel emailLabel;
    private javax.swing.JTextField mobile;
    private javax.swing.JLabel mobileLabel;
    private javax.swing.JTextField password;
    private javax.swing.JLabel passwordLabel;
    private javax.swing.JTextField postcode;
    private javax.swing.JLabel postcodeLabel;
    private javax.swing.JLabel regDateLabel;
    private javax.swing.JTextField regNo;
    private javax.swing.JLabel regNoLabel;
    private javax.swing.JButton register;
    private javax.swing.JTextField username;
    private javax.swing.JLabel usernameLabel;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a **clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: See also information about [how to format your code](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Comment: @augray I suspect that this misformatting was on purpose since questions containing only code are not allowed here (to prevent questions like this one). There needs to have some minimal proportion of text/code.

Comment: Please add a question what is not working correctly. In general try to avoid deep nested `if.. else if ... else if ... else if` structures. Your code could be changed to `if(a == null){ doSth(a); retrun;}` `if(b == null){ doSth(b); retrun;}` .. `BufferedWriter output;`

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow,

At this point I'm assuming you have been rigorously reading all the suggested material pointed out by the fine people that have supplied you with comments to assist you in acquiring the proper help you seek. After all, you haven't provided a response to some of the valid questions related to your post and,  I highly suspect that I wont receive one after this post either.

In any case I'm going to provide you with some suggestions that "I think" would improve your your code somewhat and hey....maybe even getting it working properly. Without certain specifics we can only assume what the current dilemma with your provided code might be and therefore I'm just going to take a poke at it so to speak.

To begin with, I would never put all that code into an event method. I would place it into yet another method and perhaps call it something like: **checkRegistration()** and then call that method from the event. This is the more desirable way to do things in programming:

Here is your **registerActionPerformed()** method:

```
private void registerActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    if (!checkRegistration()) {
       //Validation Failed. Do something here to
       //ensure proper data entry is carried out.
    };
}
```

Easy on the eyes and allows for other items to be added to the event without washing through all the code clutter.

Now for the **checkRegistration()** method where your validation code is housed and called from the **registerActionPerformed()** method:

```
private boolean checkRegistration() {
    String eMsg = "";
    if (compName == null){ eMsg = "Company Name Required"; }
    else if(regNo == null){ eMsg = "Registration Number Required"; }
    else if(addressL1 == null){ eMsg = "Address Required"; }
    else if(postcode == null){ eMsg = "Postal Code Required"; }
    else if(username == null){ eMsg = "Username Required"; }
    else if(password == null){ eMsg = "Password Required"; }
    else {
        eMsg = saveRegistration();
    }
    if (!"".equals(eMsg)) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(new JFrame(), eMsg, "Error",
                    JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Now, in the above method I'm assuming that you actually have variables declared somewhere which already contain the pertinent values such as *compName*, *addressL1*, *postcode*, etc. If you are pulling the data directly from specific GUI components then you will need to ensure that the variables being validated within all the '**if**' and '**else if**' statements are properly declared and filled before calling this method or, established within the method itself before the '**if**' and '**else if**' statements are processed.

For the actual saving of the registration data I have placed this code in yet another method conveniently named **saveRegistration()** and it is called from the final 'else' statement should all the validating succeed. It's better to do it this way because the method to save registration can then be called from anywhere within the class:

```
private String saveRegistration() {
    String eMsg = "";
    try {
        File user = new File(username.getText()+".txt");
        BufferedWriter output = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(user));
        //........................................
        //........... your write code ............
        //........................................
        output.close();
    }
    catch (IOException IOe) { 
        eMsg = "Error Writing To File!\n\n" + IOe.getMessage(); 
    }
    return eMsg;
}
```

Well Mihai, I hope this has helped you somewhat.